# Given two strings, str1 and str2 as input, remove all chars from str1 that appear in str2

Tags: java, string

> Given two strings, str1 and str2 as input, remove all chars from str1 that appear in str2.

**MYApproach**

In my function I took 2 Strings.In for loop I am checking each character position whether that character in string1 matches in string2.If it does not match I increment a count.If it matches I do not increment.I also checked whether count is qual to my length of second string.If it does,I then added String1 character to a new String

Below is my Updated Code for today:

```
 public String remove(String str1, String str2)
{
     String strnew="";
     int count=0;
     int p=0;
     //int j=0;
     int l1=str1.length();
     int l2=str2.length();
     for(int j=0;j<l1;)
     {
        char ch1=str1.charAt(p);
        char ch2=str2.charAt(j);
        if(ch1!=ch2)

        {   
             count++;

             j++;

           if(count==l1)
           {
             strnew=strnew+ch1;
             p++;
             j=0;
             count=0;
            }

        } 

        else
        {
            p++;
            count=0;
            j=0;
        }

     }
    return strnew;
    //write your code here


}
```

}

I am getting the following error:

```
Output       TestcaseParameters Testcase Actual Answer  Expected

No output   'Hello''World'                null             He
```

> Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have a question/

Comment: I think I am facing the last problem in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three errors in your logic:

(1) It looks like you're going through `str1`, to see if any character matches the current character in `str2`.  You keep a count of the characters that don't match.  Then, when the count reaches the limit, you decide it's not a match and you add it to the result string.

However, what's the limit?  Since you're going through `str1` (using `j`), the limit should be the number of characters in `str1`.  But you're checking `count==l2`, and `l2` is the number of characters in `str2`--the wrong one.

As it happens, the test case has the same length for both, so that's not the reason this test case is failing.  But it will cause other test cases to fail.

(2) The more serious problem is where you're doing the check.  Say you get to the last character of `str1`.  You find that the character doesn't match.  So you increment `count`, which will now equal the length of `str1`, after you fix the first problem.  So the program is supposed to check that `count` equals the length, and behave accordingly.

**But it doesn't get to that check**, because you stuck it in an `else`.  When `ch1!=ch2` is true, the program executes the body of the `if` and then skips over the `else` blocks.  The result will be that the next time it goes through the loop again, `j` is too large, and you'll get an out-of-bounds exception, which apparently this tester is unable to handle gracefully (`[object Object]`?  Really now.....)

(3) One more problem is, your code will end in only one loop.Your loop condition is based on 'l1' and you are not resetting it when the loop ends. So, if no match is found for a letter, the loop will end then and there. Since, "Hello" does not contain any 'W', the loop will end when j and 'l1' becomes equal at the fifth iteration after checking for 'W' in 'str1'.

Comment: @taiyebur I think you're right.  The OP's code sets `j=0` in some cases, which _will_ cause the loop to reset (although tampering with the loop index like this is a poor coding practice in my opinion).  But it appears that he wouldn't set `j=0` in all cases, so yes, the loop will exit prematurely.

Comment: Still 1 mistake is left.Which I am not able to correct.

Comment: Have I corrected what you told.I haven't understood your second point.

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider using more intuitive way, such as two layers of for-loop? Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
public String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    String strnew = "";
    int l1 = str1.length();
    int l2 = str2.length();
    for (int j = 0; j < l1; j++) {
        char ch1 = str1.charAt(j);
        boolean isMatched = false;
        for (int p = 0; p < l2; p++) {
            char ch2 = str2.charAt(p);
            if (ch1 == ch2) {
                isMatched = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isMatched) {
            strnew += ch1;
        }
    }
    return strnew;
}
```

Comment: Tsung-Ting Kuo I know your code runs  fine +1 for that  but I am want to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Jasonarora Thanks, I see! Sorry that I could not get the idea of your code yet - could you kindly explain more (by editing the question), or add some comments in the codes?

Answer (score 1):

Well if your parameters are "Hello" and "World"

the resulting path will be as followed for your original program:

```
String strnew = "";
l1=ch1.length()// l1 = 5
if(ch1!=ch2)   // 'H' != 'W'
   continue;
for(;j<l1;j++) // j = 1
if(ch1!=ch2)   // 'e' != 'W'
   continue;
for(;j<l1;j++) // j = 2
if(ch1!=ch2)   // 'l' != 'W'
   continue;
for(;j<l1;j++) // j = 3
if(ch1!=ch2)   // 'l' != 'W'
   continue;
for(;j<l1;j++) // j = 4
if(ch1!=ch2)   // 'o' != 'W'
   continue;
for(;j<l1;j++) // j = 5, (j < l1) is now false
break;         // (j < l1) being false causes the loop to end
return strnew; // still ""
```

Also make sure the question asks you for characters and not letters. If it asks for letters then you should either lowercase or uppercase all the letters in both strings for comparison.

Finally, the problem with your code printing object is not shown within your code here. if you directly printed the result would just not print anything since it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
function processStrings(str1, str2) {
    let str1Out="";
    let str2Out="";
    let x1 = str1.length;
    let x2 = str2.length;
    let output=[];

    for(let i=0; i < x1; i++){
        let occr = 0;
        for(let j=0; j < x2; j++){
            if(str1[i] != str2[j]){
                occr = occr+1;
                if(j == x2-1 && occr > 0){
                    str1Out = str1Out.concat(str1[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(str1[i] == str2[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
     console.log(str1Out, 'str1Out');
    for(let i=0; i < x2; i++){
        let occr = 0;
        for(let j=0; j < x1; j++){
            if(str2[i] != str1[j]){
                occr = occr+1;
                if(j == x1-1 && occr > 0){
                    str2Out = str2Out.concat(str2[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(str2[i] == str1[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(str2Out, 'str2Out');

}
```

Comment: It's not the perfect answer but fulfill all the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not getting any output, because of your first if clause.

```
if(ch1!=ch2)
```

The problem with this clause is, that it does NOT compare the values of the characters, but rather checks if they have the same address in memory.
To solve your problem you should compare the characters like this:

```
if(!ch1.equals(ch2))
```

Comment: ch1 and ch2 are of char type, which is primitive... Do you think, they are compared by address?

Comment: You're wrong on both counts.  The first `if` is correct.  The second `if` is not legal Java.