# Remove all characters from String1 which are present in String2 and vice versa

Tags: java, string

I am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I've a below question in my mind:

Print the value of Output1 and Output2 in such a way that, Output1 should print all the characters present in String1 but not in String2 and Output2 should print all the characters present in String2 but not in String1.

Example:
If String1: ABC and String: BC then Output1: A and Output2:

If String1: BC and String: BANGALORE then Output1: C and Output2: ANGALORE

I know this question looks similar to [Remove characters from the second string which are present in the first string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430262/remove-characters-from-the-second-string-which-are-present-in-the-first-string) and [Given two strings, str1 and str2 as input, remove all chars from str1 that appear in str2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839755/given-two-strings-str1-and-str2-as-input-remove-all-chars-from-str1-that-appea)
but here I want to get the result of String1 and String2 as two different strings Output1 and Output2

I've tried below program to achieve this but not sure if this is a good solution or not as I am taking four for loops to get the result.

```
package com.test.java.program;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrintString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first input as a string: ");
        String str1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter first input as a string: ");
        String str2 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(printStringOutput(str1, str2));
    }

    private static String printStringOutput(String str1, String str2){

        String strTemp1 = str1;

        int strLen1 = str1.length();
        int strLen2 = str2.length();

        for(int i=0; i<strLen1; i++){

            for(int j=0; j<strLen2; j++){

                if(str1.charAt(i) == (str2.charAt(j))){
                    str1 = str1.replace(str1.charAt(i), '\u0000');
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<strLen2; i++){

            for(int j=0; j<strLen1; j++){

                if(str2.charAt(i) == (strTemp1.charAt(j))){
                    str2 = str2.replace(str2.charAt(i), '\u0000');
                }
            }
        }

        return "Output1: " + str1 + "\nOutput2: " + str2;
    }
}
```

I know we can achieve the same result using regex expression as well but not sure how to do it. Could someone please provide a better solution for this question.

I am assuming given inputs are Strings and not performing any validations on inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: _"Could someone please provide a better solution"_ -- That is not how StackOverflow works.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  What is "better"? What does not work currently?

Comment: *"I have a question on my mind"*? Is that your way of obfuscating that you're trying to get help here doing your homework?

Comment: @clearlight: Actually this question was asked to me by one of my colleague at my workplace and I came up with above solution. I know this is a correct one but not a efficient way to get the desired output.

Comment: @Jim Garrison : This is working perfectly fine but I was looking for a solution which would be better in terms of performance as answered by Andreas. I missed to mention 'in terms of performance' in my question.   :(

Comment: Then the question is off-topic here and belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two answers (so far) produces 1-character strings as intermediate objects, which is not very efficient.

Building on [Dmitry Gorkovets's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654549/5221149), here is a better version:

```
String result1 = str1.chars()
                     .filter(ch -> str2.indexOf(ch) < 0)
                     .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                              (buf, ch) -> buf.append((char) ch),
                              StringBuilder::append)
                     .toString();
```

---

**UPDATE**

As [mentioned by Jakub M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654402/remove-all-characters-from-string1-which-are-present-in-string2-and-vice-versa/41654666?noredirect=1#comment70508744_41654666), if `str2` can be a long string, you'd get better performance by converting the String to a `Map` of characters, like this:

```
Set<Integer> set = str2.chars()
                       .boxed()
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());

String result1 = str1.chars()
                     .filter(ch -> ! set.contains(ch))
                     .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                              (buf, ch) -> buf.append((char) ch),
                              StringBuilder::append)
                     .toString();
```

Comment: Once you talk about efficiency, use a Set instead of indexOf in the filter. That makes the solution O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see any problems in your code, it works. But if you want to use Java 8 features you can use this code:

```
String str1 = "BC";
String str2 = "BANGALORE";

String result1 = str1.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
        .filter(c -> str2.indexOf(c) < 0)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

String result2 = str2.chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
        .filter(c -> str1.indexOf(c) < 0)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams you could do it like this:

```
Stream.of(str1.split(""))
      .filter((a)->!str2.contains(a))
      .forEach(System.out::print);

Stream.of(str2.split(""))
      .filter((a)->!str1.contains(a))
      .forEach(System.out::print);
```